# Is it best practice to test my Web API controllers directly or through an HTTP client?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I'm adding some unit tests for my ASP.NET Core Web API, and I'm wondering whether to unit test the controllers directly or through an HTTP client.  Directly would look roughly like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetGroups_Succeeds()
{
    var controller = new GroupsController(
        _groupsLoggerMock.Object,
        _uowRunnerMock.Object,
        _repoFactoryMock.Object
    );

    var groups = await controller.GetGroups();

    Assert.IsNotNull(groups);
}
```

... whereas through an HTTP client would look roughly like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetGroups_Succeeds()
{
    HttpClient.Execute();

    dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(HttpClient.ResponseContent);
    Assert.AreEqual(200, HttpClient.ResponseStatusCode);
    Assert.AreEqual("OK", HttpClient.ResponseStatusMsg);
    string groupid = obj[0].id;
    string name = obj[0].name;
    string usercount = obj[0].userCount;
    string participantsjson = obj[0].participantsJson;
    Assert.IsNotNull(name);
    Assert.IsNotNull(usercount);
    Assert.IsNotNull(participantsjson);
}
```

Searching online, it looks like both ways of testing an API seem to be used, but I'm wondering what the best practice is.  The second method seems a bit better because it naively tests the actual JSON response from the Web API without knowing the actual response object type, but it's more difficult to inject mock repositories this way - the tests would have to connect to a separate local Web API server that itself was somehow configured to use mock objects... I think?

Comment: I personally  unit test using the controller way, the data may change on the response, so you don't want to keep on changing the tests because you've introduced a new column in the db. But then you would have unit tests for the business logic and data layer too, this would only test if the controller succeeds. Many people say it's pointless testing the controllers as the logic should be handled in the business layer, but I do test the controllers.

Comment: If you ever start doing Domain-Driven Design (DDD), then its concept of the Application Service is the perfect point for integration tests. You test _almost_ everything, i.e. everything except the presentation-related stuff like the MVC controller, which I find ideal. Particularly with the help of SQLite, a handful of such integration tests can test the application fairly thoroughly.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Edit:  TL;DR**

The conclusion you should do both because each test serves a different purpose.

**Answer:**

This is a good question, one I often ask myself.

First, you must look at the purpose of a unit test and the purpose of an integration test.

[Unit Test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#unit-testing-controllers) :

> Unit tests involve testing a part of an app in isolation from its
> infrastructure and dependencies. When unit testing controller logic,
> only the contents of a single action are tested, not the behaviour of
> its dependencies or of the framework itself.

- Things like filters, routing, and model binding **will not** work.

[Integration Test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1) :

> Integration tests ensure that an app's components function correctly
> at a level that includes the app's supporting infrastructures, such as
> the database, file system, and network. ASP.NET Core supports
> integration tests using a unit test framework with a test web host and
> an in-memory test server.

- Things like filters, routing, and model binding **will** work.

“*Best practice*” should be thought of as “Has value and makes sense”.

You should ask yourself ***Is there any value in writing the test, or am I just creating this test for the sake of writing a test?***

Let's say your `GetGroups()` method looks like this.

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult<Group>> GetGroups()
{            
    var groups  = await _repository.ListAllAsync();
    return Ok(groups);
}
```

There is no value in writing a unit test for it! because what you are doing is testing a **mocked** implementation of `_repository`! So what is the point of that?!
The method has no logic and the repository is only going to be exactly what you mocked it to be, nothing in the method suggests otherwise.

***The Repository will have its own set of separate unit tests where you will cover the implementation of the repository methods.***

Now let's say your `GetGroups()` method is more than just a wrapper for the `_repository` and has some logic in it.

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult<Group>> GetGroups()
{            
   List<Group> groups;
   if (HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
      groups = await _repository.FindByExpressionAsync(g => g.IsAdminGroup == true);
   else
      groups = await _repository.FindByExpressionAsync(g => g.IsAdminGroup == false);

    //maybe some other logic that could determine a response with a different outcome...
    
    return Ok(groups);
}
```

Now there is value in writing a unit test for the `GetGroups()` method because the outcome could change depending on the **mocked** `HttpContext.User` value.

*Attributes like `[Authorize]` or `[ServiceFilter(….)]` **will not** be triggered in a unit test.*

.

Writing integration tests is ***almost always worth it*** because you want to test what the process will do when it forms part of an actual application/system/process.

Ask yourself, is this being used by the application/system?
If **yes**, write an integration test because the outcome depends on a combination of circumstances and criteria.

Now even if your `GetGroups()` method is just a wrapper like in the first implementation, the `_repository` will point to an actual datastore, **nothing is mocked**!

So now, not only does the test cover the fact that the datastore has data (or not), it also relies on an actual connection being made, `HttpContext` being set up properly and whether serialisation of the information works as expected.

*Things like filters, routing, and model binding **will** also work.*
So if you had an attribute on your `GetGroups()` method, for example `[Authorize]` or `[ServiceFilter(….)]`, it **will** be triggered as expected.

I use xUnit for testing so for a unit test on a controller I use this.

Controller Unit Test:

```
public class MyEntityControllerShould
{
    private MyEntityController InitializeController(AppDbContext appDbContext)
    {
        var _controller = new MyEntityController (null, new MyEntityRepository(appDbContext));            
        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
        var context = new ControllerContext(new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor()));
        _controller.ControllerContext = context;
        return _controller;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Get_All_MyEntity_Records()
    {
      // Arrange
      var _AppDbContext = AppDbContextMocker.GetAppDbContext(nameof(Get_All_MeetUp_Records));
      var _controller = InitializeController(_AppDbContext);
    
     //Act
     var all = await _controller.GetAllValidEntities();
     
     //Assert
     Assert.True(all.Value.Count() > 0);
    
     //clean up otherwise the other test will complain about key tracking.
     await _AppDbContext.DisposeAsync();
    }
}
```

The Context mocker used for unit testing.

```
public class AppDbContextMocker
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get an In memory version of the app db context with some seeded data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dbName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static AppDbContext GetAppDbContext(string dbName)
    {
        //set up the options to use for this dbcontext
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(dbName)                
            .Options;
        var dbContext = new AppDbContext(options);
        dbContext.SeedAppDbContext();
        return dbContext;
    }
}
```

The Seed extension.

```
public static class AppDbContextExtensions
{
   public static void SeedAppDbContext(this AppDbContext appDbContext)
   {
       var myEnt = new MyEntity()
       {
          Id = 1,
          SomeValue = "ABCD",
       }
       appDbContext.MyENtities.Add(myEnt);
       //add more seed records etc....

        appDbContext.SaveChanges();
        //detach everything
        foreach (var entity in appDbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
           entity.State = EntityState.Detached;
        }
    }
}
```

and for Integration Testing: ***(this is some code from a tutorial, but I can't remember where I saw it, either youtube or Pluralsight)***

setup for the TestFixture

```
public class TestFixture<TStatup> : IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the application project path where the startup assembly lives
    /// </summary>    
    string GetProjectPath(string projectRelativePath, Assembly startupAssembly)
    {
        var projectName = startupAssembly.GetName().Name;

        var applicationBaseBath = AppContext.BaseDirectory;

        var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(applicationBaseBath);

        do
        {
            directoryInfo = directoryInfo.Parent;
            var projectDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(directoryInfo.FullName, projectRelativePath));
            if (projectDirectoryInfo.Exists)
            {
                if (new FileInfo(Path.Combine(projectDirectoryInfo.FullName, projectName, $"{projectName}.csproj")).Exists)
                    return Path.Combine(projectDirectoryInfo.FullName, projectName);
            }
        } while (directoryInfo.Parent != null);

        throw new Exception($"Project root could not be located using application root {applicationBaseBath}");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The temporary test server that will be used to host the controllers
    /// </summary>
    private TestServer _server;

    /// <summary>
    /// The client used to send information to the service host server
    /// </summary>
    public HttpClient HttpClient { get; }

    public TestFixture() : this(Path.Combine(""))
    { }

    protected TestFixture(string relativeTargetProjectParentDirectory)
    {
        var startupAssembly = typeof(TStatup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        var contentRoot = GetProjectPath(relativeTargetProjectParentDirectory, startupAssembly);

        var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(contentRoot)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json");


        var webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot(contentRoot)
            .ConfigureServices(InitializeServices)
            .UseConfiguration(configurationBuilder.Build())
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .UseStartup(typeof(TStatup));

        //create test instance of the server
        _server = new TestServer(webHostBuilder);

        //configure client
        HttpClient = _server.CreateClient();
        HttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5005");
        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize the services so that it matches the services used in the main API project
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void InitializeServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var startupAsembly = typeof(TStatup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        var manager = new ApplicationPartManager
        {
            ApplicationParts = {
                new AssemblyPart(startupAsembly)
            },
            FeatureProviders = {
                new ControllerFeatureProvider()
            }
        };
        services.AddSingleton(manager);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dispose the Client and the Server
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        HttpClient.Dispose();
        _server.Dispose();
        _ctx.Dispose();
    }

    AppDbContext _ctx = null;
    public void SeedDataToContext()
    {
        if (_ctx == null)
        {
            _ctx = _server.Services.GetService<AppDbContext>();
            if (_ctx != null)
                _ctx.SeedAppDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this in the integration test.

```
public class MyEntityControllerShould : IClassFixture<TestFixture<MyEntityApp.Api.Startup>>
{
    private HttpClient _HttpClient;
    private const string _BaseRequestUri = "/api/myentities";

    public MyEntityControllerShould(TestFixture<MyEntityApp.Api.Startup> fixture)
    {
        _HttpClient = fixture.HttpClient;
        fixture.SeedDataToContext();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Get_GetAllValidEntities()
    {
        //arrange
        var request = _BaseRequestUri;

        //act
        var response = await _HttpClient.GetAsync(request);

        //assert
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); //if exception is not thrown all is good

        //convert the response content to expected result and test response
        var result = await ContentHelper.ContentTo<IEnumerable<MyEntities>>(response.Content);
        Assert.NotNull(result);
    }
}
```

**Added Edit:**
In conclusion, you should do both, because each test serves a different purpose.

Looking at the other answers you will see that the consensus is to do both.

Comment: The thing about the integration test is, doesn't it just connect to an API with a test database?  That means that the test (when testing add/update/delete/etc.) is going to modify the database, so the database state will change, introducing state into the tests.  Isn't this undesirable?  And is there a way to get around it?

Comment: Well this depends, maybe a test scenario depends an state being changed, say for instance you have to test what happens with an entity over a period of a week. You will have a range of tests. Then it's better to have an exact copy of the live/production environment to run test cases with actual data, presenting real world scenarios instead of best guess possibilities.

Comment: And what if we don't need to test that?  The test will create junk data each time that we don't want in the DB.

Comment: Then it comes back to the question of, does this test have any value in doing it? You want to make sure that you cover the processes in your api as thoroughly as possible, but without writing test just for the sake of it. Also your test database is allowed to have junk data in. It's not a backup nor is it live. What you  **do not** want to do is mock integration tests. In the example above I use an in memory data store with seeded data, so I stil test the whole integration, but destroy the data after all the tests pass. It really depends on your situation or criteria.

Comment: What I'd really like is some kind of example of restoring a .bacpac into, say, LocalDB before each integration test class runs.  That way I don't need to write a bunch of seeding code because the data's already there in the DEV database .bacpac, but it would be testing against an accurate representation of the actual database schema and data.

Comment: You could run a SQL script or a stored procedure in the initialisation of the test class that creates, populates and then drop the tables afterwards. That is beyond the scope of your question though.

Comment: Any chance you could give an example of it anyway? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I never have liked mocking in that as applications mature the effort spent on mocking can make for a ton of effort.

I like exercising endpoints by direct Http calls. Today there are fantastic tools like Cypress which allow the client requests to be intercepted and altered. The power of this feature along with easy Browser based GUI interaction blurs traditional test definitions because one test in Cypress can be all of these types Unit, Functional, Integration and E2E.

If an endpoint is bullet proof then error injection becomes impossible from outside. But even errors from within are easy to simulate. Run the same Cypress tests with Db down. Or inject intermittent network issue simulation from Cypress. This is mocking issues externally which is closer to a prod environment.

Comment: Cypress seems to be for web browsers; this is a C# client.

Comment: Yes but it has a built in HTTPClient, so it's actually more powerful than Postman or Swagger.  Merely because you can intercept inbound and outbound packets (simply).  Why make life difficult? If you start testing endpoints a little bit at a time, and add them all to your tests suite. Using the same tool you can start on Fronted rendering. So one tool, one time, one place does it all!  That's compelling. https://dev.to/jwp/angular-and-cypress-in-20-minutes-21be

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

> Is it best practice to test [...] directly **or** through an HTTP client?

Not **"or"** but **"and"**. If you serious about best practices of testing - you need both tests.

---

First test **is** a unit test. But the second one is an integration test.

There is a common consensus (test pyramid) that you need more unit tests comparing to the number of integration tests. But you need both.

There are many reasons why you should prefer unit tests over integration tests, most of them boil down to the fact that unit test are small (in all senses) and integration tests - aren't. But the main 4 are:

1. Locality

   When your unit test fails, usually, just from it's name you can figure out the place where the bug is. When integration test becomes red, you can't say right away where is the issue. Maybe it's in the `controller.GetGroups` or it's in the `HttpClient`, or there is some issue with the network.

   Also, when you introduce a bug in your code it's quite possible that only one of unit tests will become red, while with integration tests there are more chances that more than one of them will fail.
2. Stability

   With a small project which you can test on you local box you probably won't notice it. But on a big project with distributed infrastructure you will see blinking tests all the time. And that will become a problem. At some point you can find yourself not trusting test results anymore.
3. Speed

   With a small project with a small number of tests you won't notice it. But on a bit project it will become a problem. (Network delays, IO delays, initialization, cleanup, etc., etc.)
4. Simplicity

   You've noticed it yourself.

   But that not always true. If you code is poorly structured, then it's easier to write integration tests. And that's one more reason why you should prefer unit tests. In some way they force you to write more modular code (and I'm not taking about *Dependency Injection*).

But also keep in mind that **best practices** are almost always about big projects. If your project is small, and will stay small, there are a big chance that you'll be better off with strictly opposite decisions.

Write more tests. (Again, that means - both). Become better at writing tests. Delete them latter.

Practice makes perfect.

Answer (score 3):

If we limit the scope of discussion to Controller vs HttpClient testing comparison, I would say that it is better to use HttpClient. Because **if you write tests for your controllers, you're already writing integration tests already** and there is almost no point to write "weaker" integration tests while you can write stronger ones that is more realistic and also superset of the weaker ones.

For example, you can see from your own example that both of your test are testing exactly the same functionality. The different is that the latter one cover more area of testing -- JSON response, or can be something else like HTTP header you want to test. If you write the latter test, you don't need the first test at all.

I understand the pain of how to inject mocked dependencies. This requires more effort comparing to testing controller directly. However, .NET Core already provides [a good set of tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to help you on that. You can setup the test host inside the test itself, configure it and get HttpClient from it. Then you can use that HttpClient for your testing purpose.

The other concern is that it is quite a tedious task to craft HttpClient's request for each test. Anyway, [Refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit) can help you a lot on this. Refit's declarative syntax is quite easy to understand (and maintain eventually). While I would also  recommend Refit for all remote API calls, it is also suitable for ASP.NET Core integration testing.

Combining all solutions available, I don't see why you should limit to controller test while you can go for more "real" integration test with only some little more effort.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that they are not mutually exclusive. The first option is a classical unit test while the second is an integration test as involves more than a single unit of code.

If I had time to write either unit tests or integration tests, I'd pick unit tests as provides a more focused approach and gives, at least in my opinion, the best result from cost benefit.

In some particular projects where I had enough resources to write different suites of tests, I wrote both tests covering approaches. Where the second one would run without mocking anything (or maybe just the persistent storage) so I could test how all the components integrate together.

In relation to good practices, if you want to do real unit test, then you have no option but picking option one as no external dependencies are allowed (`HttpClient` is an external dependency).

Then, if the time and resources allow it, you could do integration testing for the most critical and/or complex paths.

Answer (score 2):

When doing unit test, it is important to know what are you going to test and write the tests based on your requirements. However, the second test, might looks like an integration test instead of an unit test, but I do not care to this point now!

**Between your tests**, I would recommend you to use the **second** option, because in the second unit test, you are testing your WebApi, as an WebApi, not as a class. For example suppose that you have a class with a method named `X()`. So how likely is it to write an unit test for it using Reflection? If it is completely unlikely, then writing an unit test based on Reflection is a waste of time. If it is likely, so you should write your test using Reflection too.

Moreover, using the second approach you are able to change the tech stack(For replace .Net with php) used for producing the WebApi, without changing you tests(This is what we expect from a WebApi too).

Finally, you should make a decision! how are you going to use this WebApi? How likely is it to call your WebApi using direct class instantiating?

**Note:**

It might be irrelevant to your question, but you should concentrate on your Asserts, too.  For example asserting `ResponseStatusCode` and `ResponseStatusMsg` might not be needed and you can assert only one.

Or what will happen if `obj` is null? or `obj` has more than one member?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for some non programming You can use [Postman](https://www.postman.com), and can create [collection](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/intro-to-collections/) of requests and can test multiple requests one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Swagger (aka OpenAPI).

Install Swashbuckle.AspNetCore from nuget.

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

//in  Startup.ConfigureServices

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
  {
  c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
  });
}

//in Startup.Configure

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
  app.UseSwagger();
  app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
  {
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
  });
}
```

Finally, add *"launchUrl": "swagger",* in launchSettings.json