# Guid not being found in Moq XUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm getting an issue where I can't find a GUID which I can see in the mock repo.
GetAllStudentsAsync returns the three students, on of which has the Id that I'm searching for, but always comes back null - what have I done wrong?

Method from Repo:

```
public async Task<Student> GetStudentByIdAsync(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            var Student = await dataContext.Students
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id.ToString() == id);
            return Student;
        }
        catch (DbException ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Unit test class:

```
   public class RepositoryTests
        {
            private readonly IStudentRepository MockStudentRepository;
            private readonly IClassRepository MockClassRepository;
    
            public RepositoryTests()
            {
                var mockStudentRepository = new Mock<IStudentRepository>();
                var mockClassRepository = new Mock<IClassRepository>();
                
                IList<Class> Classs = new List<Class>
                {
                    new Class
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Test Class One", Start = DateTime.Now,
                        Expiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
                    },
                    new Class
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Test Class Two", Start = DateTime.Now, 
                        Expiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3)
                    }
                };
                
                IList<Student> Students = new List<Student>()
                {
                    new Student
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Student One"
                    },
                    new Student
                    {
                        Id = new Guid(), Name = "Student Two"
                    },
                    new Student
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Student Three"
                    }
                };
                var rnd = new Random();
                foreach (var p in Students)
                {
                    p.ClassId = Classs[rnd.Next(Classs.Count)].Id.ToString();
                }
    
                mockClassRepository
                    .Setup(r => r.GetActiveClasssAsync()).ReturnsAsync(Classs);
                mockStudentRepository
                    .Setup(r => r.GetAllStudentsAsync()).ReturnsAsync(Students);
                
                MockStudentRepository = mockStudentRepository.Object;
                MockClassRepository = mockClassRepository.Object;
            }
            
            [Fact]
            public void TestCanGetAllStudents()
            {
                var Students = MockStudentRepository.GetAllStudentsAsync().Result.ToList();
                Assert.NotEmpty(Students);
                Assert.IsType<List<Student>>(Students);
            }
    
            [Fact]
            public void TestCanGetStudentById()
            {
                var Students = MockStudentRepository.GetAllStudentsAsync().Result.ToList();
                // can see there's a student with an id of "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" but fails.
                var Student = MockStudentRepository
                    .GetStudentByIdAsync("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000").Result;
                Assert.NotNull(Student);
                Assert.IsType<Student>(Student);
            }
    
        }
```

**UPDATE**

I've been playing around with sending the id parameter as a Guid type or Guid as a string. It doesn't make a difference, but yet regardless I can see the default 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 as the id, which is what I'm parsing.

Comment: Have your tried `var Student = MockStudentRepository
                    .GetStudentByIdAsync(Guid.Empty.ToString()).Result;`

Comment: Yeah, an I've tried `Guid.Parse("1A3B944E-3632-467B-A53A-206305310BAE")` which still fails. Always bringing back null.

Comment: are you able to debug into your `GetStudentByIdAsync(string id)` method?

Comment: You don't have a mock for the `GetStudentByIdAsync` method.

Comment: Perhaps you should use `GetAllStudentsAsync` method inside `GetStudentByIdAsync` instead of `dataContext.Students`

Comment: Hi @AlexanderPetrov, you're bang on. First foray into using Moq. Couldn't understand why it wasn't hitting the Repo method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set up any mock for
*`r.GetStudentByIdAsync("123")`*
eg.

`mockStudentRepository.Setup(r=> r.GetStudentByIdAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(Students[0]);`

if it is **not** set up in the mock, calling the `GetStudentByIdAsync("anything here")` will then return the default of student, which is `null`, the context within the repository is not mocked, only the method.

Calling `MockStudentRepository.GetAllStudentsAsync()` does ***not*** populate the context of the repository. Your mock setup of the `MockStudentRepository.GetAllStudentsAsync()` specifies that the list of students needs to be returned.

If you want to test the logic in your repository the best thing is to mock the data context in the repository.

Have a look at my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62815739/is-it-best-practice-to-test-my-web-api-controllers-directly-or-through-an-http-c), it might help you to set up a mock context for testing.

Another thing I noticed is that you are doing tests with `async` calls in `void` tests.

I usually use `async Task` instead of `void` eliminating the use of `.Result` to get the results.

so the test method signature would look like this:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task TestCanGetStudentById()
    {
        var Students = await MockStudentRepository.GetAllStudentsAsync();
        // can see there's a student with an id of "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" but fails.
        var Student = await MockStudentRepository
            .GetStudentByIdAsync("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");
        Assert.NotNull(Student);
        Assert.IsType<Student>(Student);
    }
```

I have had issues in the past when trying to test `async` methods in `void` Tests, especially trying to attach to the debugger.

You should then be able to step into your `public async Task<Student> GetStudentByIdAsync(string id)` method and see if `await dataContext.Students` has the mocked list of students.